# How can I show all tags from product table in laravel, when all tags are in products table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, e-commerce

This is an eCommerce project, and I stored product tags in the product table.
In the database, all tags are stored separated by commas. But how can I show all tags in view using groupBy ??

[image: Here is my database:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the database was normalized, the tags would be in their own table. But since you have them like this, I assume you're getting the products with something like:

```php
$products = Product::get();
```

If so, you can still get all **different** tags by using some collection methods.

```php
$tags_en = $products->map(fn($product) => explode(',', $product->product_tag_en))
                    ->flatten()
                    ->unique()   // avoid repeating tags
                    ->sort()     // optional
                    ->values();

$tags_bn = $products->map(fn($product) => explode(',', $product->product_tag_bn))
                    ->flatten()
                    ->unique()   // avoid repeating tags
                    ->sort()     // optional
                    ->values();
```

Comment: It's working well.
Thanks a lot @IGP

Answer (score 1):

It's not really practical to store your tags this way if you want to perform any form of meaningful query on them.

Rather, you should look to moving your tags to a separate table, either as one to many relationship (a product has many tags), or a many to many relationship, where you share tags between products. This will allow you to perform all sorts of aggregate queries like the grouping you wanted.

**One To Many**

| tags |
| --- |
| id |
| product_id |
| name |

**Many to Many**

| tags |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| product_tag |
| --- |
| product_id |
| tag_id |

The answer by @IGP is also equally valid, depending on where you want to aggregate to occur, either in the PHP client, or the actual database query.